# Simple Delete from table but I got this error "Must declare the scalar variable "@Senduserid" "

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, aspxgridview, delete-row

I have a Gridview in my page Which I can Select each row i want by using checkbox   when i 
select a row in Gridview and click on Delete button  igot this error **"Must declare the scalar variable "@Senduserid" "** 
here's the Delete button code

```
protected void btnMultipleRowDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Looping through all the rows in the  GridView

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkRows");

        //Check if the checkbox is checked. 
        //value in the  CheckBox's Value property is set as the //value of the delete command's  parameter.

        while (checkbox.Checked)
        {
            // Retreive the  ID
            int ida = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);

            // Pass the  value of the selected Employye ID to the Delete 
            //These numbers indicate in which order tables shoulde be deleted  
            /*1*/
            new BLL.LoginBLL().Delete(ida);
            /*2*/
            new BLL.MessageBLL().Delete(ida);
            /*3*/
            new BLL.JointBLL().Delete(ida);                    
            /*4*/
            new BLL.Tempprice().Delete(ida);                    
            /*5*/
            new BLL.LotsBLL().Delete(ida);
            /*6*/
            new BLL.AuctionBLL().Delete(ida);
            /*7*/
            new BLL.ProfileBLL().DeleteProfile(ida);

            checkbox.Checked = false;
        }
        //refresh the Gridview rows
        ShowUsers();
    }
}
```

And code of  the place I got this error:`

```
public bool Delete(int Id)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        string text = string.Format("Delete From {0} where {1} = @{1} or {2} =@{2}"
                                        , Common.Data.MessageInfo.TableName
                                        , Common.Data.MessageInfo.SenduseridField
                                        ,Common.Data.MessageInfo.RecuseridField);
        cmd.CommandText = text;
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@" + Common.Data.MessageInfo.SenduseridField, Id);
        param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        param = new SqlParameter("@" + Common.Data.MessageInfo.RecuseridField, Id);
        param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        cmd.Connection = this.GetConnection();
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return true;
    }
}
```

DataBase Relationship

[image: DataBase Relationship]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You instantiate two parameters, but you don't add the first parameter to the command. Before you instantiate the recuseridfield parameter, add the senduseridfield parameter to the command's parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd.CommandText = text;             
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@" + Common.Data.MessageInfo.SenduseridField, Id);             
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;        
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);             // you  over looked this 

param = new SqlParameter("@" + Common.Data.MessageInfo.RecuseridField, Id);             
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;             
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);             

cmd.Connection = this.GetConnection();             
cmd.Connection.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify DataKeyNames property of Gridview Control.

```
DataKeyNames="Senduserid"
```